# Best approach to figure out where array stops at

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have 4 different types of random array with a length of 5 that the input can provide.

```
[0,4,4,0,0]
[1,2,3,4,0]
[2,4,6,4,5]
[3,6,0,8,9]
```

What's a good way to figure out where the number ends(becomes 0 and no numbers after that), assuming the array input is always in the length of 5?

I should get a value of index like respectively to the array above

```
2
3
4
4
```

I know of a way but it takes a lot of if and for statements and slows down the flow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the last result 5, and not 4? Also, please include your current code

Comment: What does `4 different types of random array` mean?

Comment: yeah last result should be 4,my bad.

Comment: bassically a user enters 4 seperate inputs, and they will be converted to a array 
 format, hence random array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop and a speed way if the last number of the array isn't a 0.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0];

if(arr[arr.length -1] != 0)
{
  console.log(arr.length -1)
}
else
{
  for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >=0; i--)
  {
    if(arr[i] == 0 && i != 0 && arr[i -1] != 0)
    {
      console.log(i - 1);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 for loops, compare the current value and use the index of the current array to get the index, where the array ends.

```js
var arr = [
  [0,4,4,0,0],
  [1,2,3,4,0],
  [2,4,6,4,5],
  [3,6,0,8,9],
];
          
for (var i = 0, ilen = arr.length; i < ilen; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, jlen = arr[i].length; j < jlen; j++) {
    if (arr[i][j] === 0) {
      console.log('array ' + i + ' ends at index:', j);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, but you could map it and get the final length

```
.map(a=>a.map((b,i)=>a.slice(i+1).filter(c=>c!=0).length > 0 || b != 0).filter(b=>b).length - 1)
```

```js
var x = [[0,4,4,0,0],
[1,2,3,4,0],
[2,4,6,4,5],
[3,6,0,8,9]]

console.log(
  x.map(a=>a.map((b,i)=>a.slice(i+1).filter(c=>c!=0).length > 0 || b != 0).filter(b=>b).length - 1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an excellent usecase for `reduce`'s less popular sibling `reduceRight`. This simple lambda function will work for any size of array.

```
yourArray.reduceRight((acc, val, index) => val && !acc ? index : acc, 0)
```

Comment: I agree iterating from the right is logical, but you still have the same number of iterations, and if you use `reduce` instead, you can drop `!acc` and it will still work (this is actually the solution in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

A simple traditional `for` loop will do the job.

```
var array = [0, 4, 4, 0, 0];

for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0 && array[i] === 0; i --) {}

console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply turn the subarray into a string, replace all trailing zeros, and take the strings length - 1

```js
let arrs = [
    [0, 4, 4, 0, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 0],
    [2, 4, 6, 4, 5],
    [3, 6, 0, 8, 9]
];

const res = arrs.map(arr => 
    arr.join('').replace(/0+$/g, '').length - 1
);
console.log(res);
```

That uses only a single loop just to target every subarray and not a single if.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below solution helps,

```js
const inp = [[0,4,4,0,0], [1,2,3,4,0], [2,4,6,4,5], [3,6,0,8,9]]

let stopPosition = inp.map(arr=>{
 let findZeros = arr.join('').match(/[1-9][^1-9]+$/)
 return findZeros !== null ? findZeros["index"] : "No stop position"
 }
)

console.log(stopPosition) 
//[ 2, 3, 'No stop position', 'No stop position' ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the 4th value in your example should be 4 and not 5, you can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and for each iteration, return the current index if the current value is not 0 :

```
[0,4,4,0,0].reduce((accumulator, currentItem, currentIndex) => currentItem !== 0 ? currentIndex : accumulator, 0)
```

1st iteration, currentItem is 0, returns 0
2nd iteration, currentItem is 4, returns current index : 1
3rd iteration, currentItem is 4, returns current index : 2
4th iteration, currentItem is 0, returns accumulator : 2
5th iteration, currentItem is 0, returns accumulator : 2

**Edit**: More readable version :

```
[0,4,4,0,0].reduce((accumulator, currentItem, currentIndex) => {
  return currentItem !== 0 ? currentIndex : accumulator
}, 0)
```